# SyntaxError: 'return' outside function en Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios, float, integer

Con este código estoy intentando crear un diccionario desde un archivo. El archivo tiene una línea en blanco y lo que quiero es imprimir la advertencia, pero que igualmente me genere el diccionario. Me genera un error de sintaxis que no sé cómo interpretar (imagino que es producto de cómo está indentando el código).
Gracias!

```
import csv

def leer_precios(nombre_archivo):
    '''Computa el precio total del camion (cajones*precio) de un archivo'''
precios = {} 

with open('Data/precios.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split(',')
            #rows = csv.reader(f)        
        try: 
                precios[row[0]] = float(row[1])
                #print(precios)
        except IndexError:
                print('Lista indexada está fuera de rango. Puede haber una línea vacía en el archivo')
                #pass
    return precios
    precios= leer_precios('Data/precios.csv')
print(precios)
```

Comment: Tienes mal la identación del código de la función, todo tiene que ir un nivel más adentro.

Comment: Si, no me había dado cuenta que el with open estaba al mismo nivel que la definición de la función. Gracias, yo lo pude corregir!